# Oracle's to_date function returns a non existing date

Tags: java, oracle, date, datetime

When `java.util.Date` is parsing `"01/01/1901"` to a `Date` objet, Java API is converting the date to `“01/01/1901 0:08:39”` instead of `“01/01/1901 0:00:00”` and this is happening only for Malaysia time zone.

This is happening because in 1901 Malaysia decided to synchronize his time zone with  Penang, Malacca and Singapore and for that reason they added 8 minutes and 39 seconds. Java knows this and for that reason is automatically adding minutes and seconds to the date object (Because in Malaysia the  hour      00:00:00 doesn’t exist for date 01/01/1991).

Malaysia TZ change:
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/malaysia/kuala-lumpur?year=1901

Java Source:

```
public class SimpleDateFormatExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        // Locale for formatter
        Locale malaysianLocale = new Locale("ms", "MY");
        // Default date and time format for Malaysia
        DateFormat defaultMalaysianFormatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, malaysianLocale);
        // This step is crucial
        TimeZone malaysianTimeZone= TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
        defaultMalaysianFormatter.setTimeZone(malaysianTimeZone);
        try {
            format.setTimeZone(malaysianTimeZone);
            Date a = format.parse("01/01/1901");
            String t = defaultMalaysianFormatter.format(a);
            System.out.println(t);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Example java output:

> 01 Januari 1901 12:08:39 AM

In Oracle Database `TO_date` function is not working in the same fashion, we believe that Oracle database doesn’t consider the time zone and for that reason it is not retrieving the correct values when send via SQL query.

Oracle Sql Source:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Asia/Kuala_Lumpur';
select to_date('19010101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Example Oracle output:

> 01-JAN-01 00:00:00

This issues are specific for Malaysia Time zone and for 1901 01/01

Why Java and Oracle database are behaving in different fashion?

Comment: A date (in Oracle) does not have a location or time zone. If you want a time zone then use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` data type.

Comment: That function will break, I tried it. 
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('19010101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur') FROM DUAl;                                                    
And oracle thrown an exeption: ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
*Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
*Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment:

A `DATE` data type does not have a location or time zone. If you want that then you need to use a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Asia/Kuala_Lumpur';

SELECT FROM_TZ(
         CAST(
           DATE '1901-01-01' + INTERVAL '08:39' MINUTE TO SECOND
           AS TIMESTAMP
         ),
         'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
       )
FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

```
1901-01-01 00.09.04.000000000 ASIA/KUALA_LUMPUR
```

Specifying any value between `1900-01-01 00:00:00` and `1900-01-01 00:08:38` will give `ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval` as Oracle knows it is an invalid date/time/time zone combination.

Why the output is `00:09:04` and not `00:08:39` is another question...

You can also use an ANSI timestamp literal:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1901-01-01 00:08:39 Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: On my DB's I always get "01.01.1901 00:08:39 +06:55" for  `FROM_TZ(CAST(DATE '1901-01-01' + INTERVAL '08:39' MINUTE TO SECOND AS TIMESTAMP), 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')`. Tested on 11.1.0.7.0, 11.2.0.3.0 and 12.1.0.2